# Compilation error when trying to get system version in Xcode 7 beta 4

Tags: xcode, swift2, ios9

I am getting the following error when i try to get the system version

```
 //let Device = UIDevice.currentDevice() //this line also cause a compilation error
 let iosVersion = NSString(string: Device.systemVersion).doubleValue
```

Command /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc failed with exit code 1

Comment: How did you find the error was connected to that command?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
let theDevice = UIDevice.currentDevice().systemVersion
```

this will give you 9.0.1 for example for ios 9.01